# confused about CPython threading.Thread source code -- start and join

Tags: python, multithreading

```
def start(self):
    """Start the thread's activity.

    It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the
    object's run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

    This method will raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the
    same thread object.

    """
    if not self._initialized:
        raise RuntimeError("thread.__init__() not called")

    if self._started.is_set():
        raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
    with _active_limbo_lock:  
        _limbo[self] = self
    try:
        _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())

    except Exception:
        with _active_limbo_lock:
            del _limbo[self]
        raise
    self._started.wait()
```

can't understand what meaning of the last: self._started.wait(). Event object wait will  block the calling thread.  but I have't see any to notify it.

```
def join(self, timeout=None):

    if not self._initialized:
        raise RuntimeError("Thread.__init__() not called")
    if not self._started.is_set():
        raise RuntimeError("cannot join thread before it is started")
    if self is current_thread():
        raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")

    if timeout is None:
        self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
    else:
        # the behavior of a negative timeout isn't documented, but
        # historically .join(timeout=x) for x<0 has acted as if timeout=0
        self._wait_for_tstate_lock(timeout=max(timeout, 0))

def _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block=True, timeout=-1):

    lock = self._tstate_lock
    if lock is None:  # already determined that the C code is done
        assert self._is_stopped
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
        lock.release()
        self._stop()
```

the doc say:  join() until the thread terminates.This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates -- either normally or through an unhandled exception or until the optional timeout occurs.

so I don't understand how join to terminates thread. because thread terminates -- is happend in at _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ()). _start_new_thread will return  new thread id and the new thread exit when ._bootstrap->_bootstrap_inner->self.run() return or terminates with an unhandled exception。

Comment: (1)`_start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())` runs `self._bootstrap()` (in a new thread) which calls `self._bootstrap_inner()` where `self._started` is set. (2) Unfortunately I don't understand your question regarding `join()`.

Comment: oh nice u first answer solved my problem。thanks very much。

Answer (score 0):

The `_started` event gets set in the `_bootstrap_inner` method, right near the top:

```
def _bootstrap_inner(self):
    try:
        self._set_ident()
        self._set_tstate_lock()
        self._started.set()
        ...
```

This code also shows where the thread state lock gets acquired, in the `_set_tstate_lock` method, which is relevant to the second part of your question. The thread state lock is a special "sentinel" lock that gets released automatically by the interpreter when the thread shuts down. It's not controlled by Python code, but by stuff in C. The `join` method doesn't *cause* a thread to shut down, it just waits for it to shut down on its own, and then does some cleanup on the `Thread` object afterwards. The thread state lock being released (by the interpreter) is the signal it gets that the thread has stopped running.

Comment: thanks.  maybe I  understand u mean.  it is :  new thread call self._bootstrap() -> call _bootstrap_inner -> call self._set_tstate_lock() will got a sentinel lock that will be released automatically by the interpreter when the thread shuts down.   so the join()  call _wait_for_tstate_lock() will have 2 result.:
         1 already determined that the C code is done. raise exception
         2 lock.acquire will block until thread is shutdown = interpreter release sentinel lock

Comment: another problem:  I guess don't call join() is also ok。 not any problem right？